# Can access /var/lib/mysql-files but not /home/username/Desktop/temp?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, mysql

I'm using `mysql workbench` to export my `mysql` database table to a `.csv` file using the statement.

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/temporary2.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM parts;
```

This statement is working fine but if I change the path to `/home/zaid/Desktop/temp` then I get a `Error Code: 1. Can't create/write to file '/home/zaid/Desktop/temp/temp.csv' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)` error

I have `chmod 1777` both directories but `/home/zaid/Desktop/temp` doesn't work.

`ls -l` for both the directories:

```
drwxrwxrwt 2 mysql mysql     4096 Aug  6 14:06 temp

drwxrwxrwt 2 mysql mysql     4096 Aug  6 14:26 mysql-files
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a permission problem, have a look at the permissions for directory '/home/zaid/Desktop'? They have to be fixed aswell, or at least the mysql-user has to be in the correct group.